# Solve an ordinary sec0nd order differential equation for an LC circuit using Laplace Transforms. (5.3-65)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Please check my setup for this very simple $LC$ circuit. But first assume the given differential equation is correct. There is no need to open a physics or design of electric circuits book as in its very essence this is just a problem in solving a differential equation with Laplace transforms. I just need my **Setup** checked which comes after the section entitled **Given**.

**Given**:

All elements are in series: $L=1$ $henrys$, $C=1 farads$, $v(t)=1-e^{-t}$ $volts$ for $(0<t<\pi)$. The emf $v(t)=0$ for all $t$ outside the given interval. We have an initial condition of $i(0)=0$ for current and zero charge on the capacitor. Our goal is to find the current $i(t)$ in the circuit once the switch is closed.

The following differential equation models this physical problem...

$$Li'+\frac{1}{C}\int i(t)dt=v(t)$$

Because all units are compatible with this equation we can just plug in their values to simplify this equation giving us...

$$i'+\int i(t)dt=v(t)$$

That was the "given." The rest is just a math problem of solving a very simple differential equation with Laplace transforms. The next section is what I need checked.

**Setup**: (Please check this for me)

First express $v(t)=1-e^{-t}$ in terms of unit steps for $(0<t<\pi)$...

$$v(t)=(1-e^{-t})u(t)-(1-e^{-t})u(t-\pi)$$

$$=(1-e^{-t})u(t)+e^{-t}u(t-\pi)-u(t-\pi)$$

an adjustment is needed for the exponential factor in the middle term as follows...

$$e^{-t}=e^{-(t-\pi+\pi)}=e^{-\pi}e^{-(t-\pi)}$$

our short lived forcing function now looks like this...

$$v(t)=(1-e^{-t})u(t)+e^{-\pi}e^{-(t-\pi)}u(t-\pi)-u(t-\pi)$$

the following is the equation that we need to take the Laplace transform of where capital $I=\mathcal{L}\{i(t)\}$...

$$i'+\int i(t)dt=(1-e^{-t})u(t)+e^{-\pi}e^{-(t-\pi)}u(t-\pi)-u(t-\pi)$$

$$sI+\frac{1}{s}I=\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s+1}+e^{-\pi(s+1)}\frac{1}{s+1}-\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s}$$

$$I(s^2+1)=1-\frac{s}{s+1}+e^{-\pi(s+1)}\frac{s}{s+1}-e^{-\pi s}$$

**My Question**:

This is actually a request. I just need the setup for this problem carefully examined more for methodical errors than simply arithmetic errors. I am especially interested in if I made the correct shift adjustments and if my resulting Laplace transforms were accurately taken. Could I have set up my unit steps better?

Comment: @Julián Aguirre could I trouble you to look at this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis of the voltage is correct, but you make it unnecessarily harder than it has to be. Since $v(t) = 1-e^{-t}$ for $t\in(0,\pi)$ and zero otherwise, the Laplace transform is
$$
\int_0^{\infty}(1-e^{-t})e^{-st}dt = \int_0^{\pi}(1-e^{-t})e^{-st}dt + \int_{\pi}^{\infty}0\cdot e^{-st}dt
$$
By using the definition instead of trying to rewrite the expression, we can immediately determine the Laplace transform of $v(t)$ to be
$$
\frac{1-e^{-\pi s}}{s} - \frac{1-e^{-\pi(s+1)}}{s+1}
$$
Then the left hand side is as you have determined
$$
I(s)(s+1/s) = \frac{1-e^{-\pi s}}{s} - \frac{1-e^{-\pi(s+1)}}{s+1}
$$